# How to release from Jiu Jitsu throw?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, jujutsu, escapes

Please refer to [video at 3:46](https://youtu.be/S1X6sfQO_Tw?t=3m46s). 
As can be seen one of the fighters lift the other guy and he twists his legs at the high point and release as he reaches the floor.

What is this release called and where can I find tutorial for it?
In addition, is there a source for releases in case you are already caught?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rickson Gracie escapes this pick-up by

1. pre-emptively jumping for an arm-in guillotine choke grip rather than waiting for his opponent to initiate the throw, then
2. hip switching, then
3. drawing on raw elite athleticism, and finally
4. by his opponent failing to secure any grip for a true double-leg, suplex, or anything other orthodox technique

Rickson doesn't use a specific "release" or escape. To replicate this performance you should not focus on this particular technique, but rather on general agility, proprioception, and body awareness during uncooperative grappling with a partner.

Comment: Agreed. You can train this (kind of) standard movement for escaping throws (half-twist, counter-directional) through gymnastics or, as this is easiest, against tomoe-nage. Without an opponent losing control this does not help much in general, though.

Comment: As curiosity, here in Brazil we call ``Pilão``. It means something like "Pestle".

Comment: @gpupo What do you call Pilão? The throw, the escape, or something else?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann The throw